# expo-video-player using a videoRef in this simple lib

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

Just trying to create a ref to the VideoPlayer component - as this should come with a bunch of Expo video playback functions attached. ?

[Docs](https://github.com/ihmpavel/expo-video-player#props) say to just add a ref in the params `videoRef`.. so I did:

```
        constructor(props) {                                                                                                                       
            super(props);                                                                                                                           
            this.videoRef = React.createRef();                                                                                                      
            this.state = {                                                                                                                          
            };                                                                                                                                      
          }; 

          <VideoPlayer                                                                                                                      
            videoProps={{                                                                                                                   
              shouldPlay: false,                                                                                                            
              resizeMode: Video.RESIZE_MODE_CONTAIN,                                                                                        
              source: {                                                                                                                     
                uri: this.props.navigation.state.params.videoUrl,                                                                           
              },                                                                                                                            
            }}                                                                                                                              
            videoRef={this.videoRef}                                                                                                 
            isLooping={true}                                                                                                                
            inFullscreen={true}                                                                                                             
            videoBackground='transparent'                                                                                                   
            height={height}                                                                                                                 
            width={width}                                                                                                                   
            showControlsOnLoad={true}                                                                                                       
          />
```

Result after rendering video:
`this.videoRef == Object { "current": null }`

Further investigation:
[In the code](https://github.com/ihmpavel/expo-video-player/blob/master/lib/index.tsx#L117) - type is `Video` for `videoRef`?
Docs seem to expect a `ref` as the type. Not sure I understand how I would pass a `Video` component to `videoRef param` in a `VideoPlayer` component. This is what is making me a little confused.

Any help would be awesome - thanks.

Comment: Hello,
Could you try to replace 'videoRef={this.videoRef}' with 'videoRef={(a) => this.videoRef = a}' and let me know ?

Comment: And also try ref={(a) => (videoRef = a)} ?

Comment: I figured this out and posted the answer - cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documenation is wrong. `videoRef` is expected as a part of `videoProps` value.
Also the docs say the type expected is a ref, this is also wrong. The code is expecting a function.

```
   _handleVideoRef = (component) => {
      this.videoPlayerRef = component;
    }

      <VideoPlayer                                                                                                                              
        videoProps={{                                                                                                                                  
          videoRef: this._handleVideoRef,     /* THIS IS CORRECT*/                                                                                                           
          shouldPlay: false,                                                                                                                           
          resizeMode: Video.RESIZE_MODE_CONTAIN,                                                                                                       
          source: {                                                                                                                                    
            uri: this.props.navigation.state.params.videoUrl,                                                                                          
          },                                                                                                                                           
        }}                                                                                                                                             
        isLooping={true}                                                                                                                               
        inFullscreen={true}                                                                                                                            
        videoBackground='transparent'                                                                                                                  
        height={height}                                                                                                                                
        width={width}                                                                                                                                  
        showControlsOnLoad={true}                                                                                                                      
      />
```